# Python syntax error time arguments

Tags: python, time, arguments, syntax-error

I have this script

```
for i in ['1', '2', '3'] :
  (time python quicksort6.py qs-input.$i)  > qs-output.$i 2>&1
  uname -a >> qs-output.$i
  who >> qs-output.$i
```

which runs a Python file (`quicksort6.py`) which takes 3 files as an input argument (that's why loop).

The problem is that I take this error

```
 File "run.py", line 3    
     (time python quicksort6.py qs-input.$i)  > qs-output.$i 2>&1
             ^       
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help?

Comment: This looks like a combination between a shell script and a python script.  Which one are you intending it to be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  To make material appear as code, highlight it in the editor and use the **`{}`** button above to indent the material as code.  I hope I've revised your material to match what you've got, because frankly, what I see is a confusing mixture of Python and shell script, but that's what seemed to be present in the question.  The errors you get are consistent with what you'd get trying to run the shell code (line 2-4) with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "driver" script most likely is supposed to be a shell script (usually named `something.sh`).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3; do
    $(time python quicksort6.py qs-input.$i) > qs-output.$i 2>&1
    uname -a >> qs-output.$i
    who >> qs-output.$i
done
```

We could also make it a python script, but it would be much more messy.  Up to you.

Comment: It is a python script which I run it through Shell

Comment: quicksort.py is a python script.  Are you saying that the code you posted is also supposed to be a python script?  Because if so it needs much more work to turn it into a legal, functional python script.  But as you can see, very little work was needed to turn it into a legal, functional shell script.

Comment: thanks jedwards..

This is not a python file it is a shell script.. I did what you said in the first line. I created a something.sh and I ran it (sh something.sh) and it worked like a charm!!

thanks!!!